# Barryvdh/Dompdf blank page issue and large text is not displaying to next page in PDF

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am getting some issue of blank pages in Barryvdh/Dompdf package while generating PDF. It does not render large text content to the next page and displays underneath the bottom of the page.

It also adds 2 blank pages after each content displaying page, I have spent a lot of time but still could not find any solution.

I have tried many solutions like to not set any fixed height in HTML, removed  and , minified HTML, validate HTML tags and many others.

Please have a look at this code and let me know if there is an issue?

This is my PHP code to view PDF in the browser.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.abc',compact('data', 'user', 'categories'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
return $pdf->stream('survey.pdf');
```

and this is my view HTML file code.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Local Survey</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style>
    td {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #0a2238;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50%; vertical-align: middle;">
        <img src="images/logo-short.svg" style="width: 50px; display: inline-block; margin-right:
                        10px; vertical-align: middle;" />
        <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:
                        middle;">Your Trust Score</span>
      </td>
      <td style="width:50%; vertical-align: middle;
                    text-align: right;">
        <h3 style="font-size: 20px;"> Local Survey</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family:'Oswald',
                        sans-serif;">Overall Customer Trust Score</h1>
        <div class="overall-score">
          <div class="score-wrapper" style="width:300px; height:350px; margin:0 auto;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
            <img src="images/overall-score-icon.png" style="width:300px; " />
            <div style="position: relative; top:-240px; text-align: center;">
              <div class="score" style="font-size:
                                    80px;line-height: 80px;">12</div>
              <div class="slash" style="background: #0a2238;
                                    height: 2px;
                                    width: 150px;
                                    margin: 10px auto;"></div>
              <div class="total" style="font-size: 40px;
                                    line-height: 40px;">100</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <td width="20%" style="text-align: center; width:20%">
              <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color:#0a2238;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;margin:0 0 20px;">
                Visibility</h4>
              <img src="images/visibility.svg" style="width: 70px;" />
              <p style="font-size: 20px;line-height: 1;font-family:
                                        'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:
                                        #0a2238; font-weight: bold;margin:0;">2</p>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" style="text-align: center; width:20%">
              <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color:#0a2238;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;margin:0 0 20px;">
                Reputation</h4>
              <img src="images/reputation.svg" style="width: 70px;" />
              <p style="font-size: 20px;line-height: 1;font-family:
                                        'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:
                                        #0a2238; font-weight: bold;margin:0;">3</p>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" style="text-align: center; width:20%">
              <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color:
                                    #0a2238;margin:0 0 20px;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;">Experience</h4>
              <img src="images/experience.svg" style="width:70px;" />
              <p style="font-size: 20px;line-height: 1;font-family:
                                    'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:
                                    #0a2238; font-weight: bold;margin:0;">4</p>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" style="text-align: center; width:20%">
              <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color:
                                    #0a2238;margin:0 0 20px;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;">Security</h4>
              <img src="images/security.svg" style="width:70px;" />
              <p style="font-size: 20px;line-height: 1;font-family:
                                    'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:
                                    #0a2238; font-weight: bold;margin:0;">2</p>
            </td>
            <td width="20%" style="text-align: center; width:20%">
              <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color: #0a2238; margin:0 0 20px;
                                    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;">Re-Engagement</h4>
              <img src="images/engagement.svg" style="width:70px;" />
              <p style="font-size: 20px;line-height:
                                    1;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight:
                                    bold;color:
                                    #0a2238; font-weight: bold; margin:0;">2</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; text-align: center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%; background: #0B79B9; padding: 10px;"></td>
      <td style="width:20%; background: #EF8B21; padding: 10px;"></td>
      <td style="width:20%; background: #1996A0; padding: 10px;"></td>
      <td style="width:20%; background: #4FA246; padding: 10px;"></td>
      <td style="width:20%; background: #E44F2B; padding: 10px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial; padding-bottom: 25px; text-align: justify;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif">Trust for Local Business is just like a funnel.
          <img style="padding-left: 50px;float: right;width: 40%;" src="images/funnel.png">
        </h2>
        <p>Initially, when a potential buyer is trying to find a product or service, they are going to do broad, high-level keyword searches online to see what options are available.
        </p>

        <p><strong>This is the Online Presence</strong> level, and is the widest part of the funnel. At t his stage you need to make sure that yvou have an attractive, user-friendly website, a fully completed Google My Business profile, and that your business
          information is updated and accurate on all of the major Business Directories online.
        </p>
        <p>
          Once the potential buyer discovers all the available options, they then look at
          <strong>Online
                        Reputation</strong> for social validation. Statistically, 97% of people read reviews for local businesses, which means that if you want to stand out, you need to make sure that you’re actively collecting and displaying
          raving, recent, relevant reviews in the right places online.
        </p>
        <p class="text-justify">
          Once the customer feels confident in your Online Presence and Online Reputation, they then decide whether or not to engage in a potential transaction. This is where your On-Site Presence becomes very important. Regardless of whether customers visit you
          (brick &amp; mortar), or you visit your customers (service-based), cleanliness, promptness, product/service quality, and friendliness all play important roles in the overall customer experience, and ultimately become the deciding factor as to
          whether a customer buys from you.
        </p>
        <p>
          Once a customer has made a purchase, and has made their way through the funnel, it’s important that you have Re-engagement Tools and processes in place to stay involved in your customer’s life, and to keep bringing them back over and over again. </p>
        <p>Your Customer Trust Score is based on the 4 Criteria Above and it’s based out of a score of 100 points. Each of the 4 criteria contribute 25 points to the overall score because they are all equally important and relevant to customer trust in different
          ways.
        </p>
        <h2 style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif">Your Local Business Customer Trust Score is: 22</h2>
        <p>
          Here’s how your score breaks down…
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial; padding-bottom: 25px; text-align: justify;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%; text-align:center;">
        <div class="overall-score">
          <div class="score-wrapper" style="width:175px; height:175px; margin:0 auto;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
            <img src="images/visibility-score-icon.png" style="width:175px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;" />
            <div style="position: relative; top:-140px; text-align: center;">
              <div class="score" style="font-size:
                                    60px;line-height: 50px;">2</div>
              <div class="slash" style="background: #0a2238;
                                    height: 2px;
                                    width: 100px;
                                    margin: 10px auto;"></div>
              <div class="total" style="font-size: 36px;
                                    line-height: 36px;">20</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 style="color: #0B79B9; text-align: center;">Visibility & Online Presence</h3>
        <ul style="text-align:center;padding: 0; margin:0 auto">
          <li style="display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Bad
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Poor
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Good
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Great
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70%; border-left: 10px solid #0B79B9; padding-left: 30px;">
        <h3 style="color: #0b79b9;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    font-size: 24px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;">Items You Need to Improve:</h3>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

          <div style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;">

            question_name<span style="color: #0b79b9;">No</span>
          </div>
          <div class="answer">

            <table style="width: 100%;">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:10%;">name</td>
                <td>
                  <img src="images/icon-star-filled.png" style="width:25px;" />
                  <img src="images/icon-star-empty.png" style="width:25px;" />

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <table style="width: 100%; background: #0A2238; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 30px; vertical-align: top;">
                  <img src="images/check-square.png" />
                </td>
                <td style="color: #fff; vertical-align: top; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                  name
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            Having a Facebook Business page has a lot of benefits. For starters, Facebook has 1.19 Billion users, who you can target right down to the town or city that you live in. The great thing about Facebook, is that it’s a social network, which means that there
            are a lot of opportunities for people to talk about and recommend your products and services between each other. Word of mouth on Facebook can spread quickly, and have a significant impact on your business. Facebook also has laser targeted
            ads that you can run very economically that can be drilled down to very specific niches within your demographics, such as gender, age, birthday, location, interests, relationship status, language, education level, and the list goes on and
            on… And, thanks to Facebook’s analytics (called FB Insights), you can see exactly what type of impact your ads are having. Facebook also gives you the opportunity to connect with your customers on a personal level. People can like, follow
            you, and even engage you and your staff through comments and FB Messenger. All of these interactions help to create a sense of connectedness and community between you and your existing and future potential customers. In addition, having a
            FB Business page can also help in you in the search engines. Because FB is such a massive website, often your FB Business page will show up in Google search, giving you even more exposure online - which means more opportunities for new potential
            buyers to find you. Having a Facebook Business page has a lot of benefits. For starters, Facebook has 1.19 Billion users, who you can target right down to the town or city that you live in. The great thing about Facebook, is that it’s a social
            network, which means that there are a lot of opportunities for people to talk about and recommend your products and services between each other. Word of mouth on Facebook can spread quickly, and have a significant impact on your business.
            Facebook also has laser targeted ads that you can run very economically that can be drilled down to very specific niches within your demographics, such as gender, age, birthday, location, interests, relationship status, language, education
            level, and the list goes on and on… And, thanks to Facebook’s analytics (called FB Insights), you can see exactly what type of impact your ads are having. Facebook also gives you the opportunity to connect with your customers on a personal
            level. People can like, follow you, and even engage you and your staff through comments and FB Messenger. All of these interactions help to create a sense of connectedness and community between you and your existing and future potential customers.
            In addition, having a FB Business page can also help in you in the search engines. Because FB is such a massive website, often your FB Business page will show up in Google search, giving you even more exposure online - which means more opportunities
            for new potential buyers to find you. Having a Facebook Business page has a lot of benefits. For starters, Facebook has 1.19 Billion users, who you can target right down to the town or city that you live in. The great thing about Facebook,
            is that it’s a social network, which means that there are a lot of opportunities for people to talk about and recommend your products and services between each other. Word of mouth on Facebook can spread quickly, and have a significant impact
            on your business. Facebook also has laser targeted ads that you can run very economically that can be drilled down to very specific niches within your demographics, such as gender, age, birthday, location, interests, relationship status, language,
            education level, and the list goes on and on… And, thanks to Facebook’s analytics (called FB Insights), you can see exactly what type of impact your ads are having. Facebook also gives you the opportunity to connect with your customers on
            a personal level. People can like, follow you, and even engage you and your staff through comments and FB Messenger. All of these interactions help to create a sense of connectedness and community between you and your existing and future potential
            customers. In addition, having a FB Business page can also help in you in the search engines. Because FB is such a massive website, often your FB Business page will show up in Google search, giving you even more exposure online - which means
            more opportunities for new potential buyers to find you. Having a Facebook Business page has a lot of benefits. For starters, Facebook has 1.19 Billion users, who you can target right down to the town or city that you live in. The great thing
            about Facebook, is that it’s a social network, which means that there are a lot of opportunities for people to talk about and recommend your products and services between each other. Word of mouth on Facebook can spread quickly, and have a
            significant impact on your business. Facebook also has laser targeted ads that you can run very economically that can be drilled down to very specific niches within your demographics, such as gender, age, birthday, location, interests, relationship
            status, language, education level, and the list goes on and on… And, thanks to Facebook’s analytics (called FB Insights), you can see exactly what type of impact your ads are having. Facebook also gives you the opportunity to connect with
            your customers on a personal level. People can like, follow you, and even engage you and your staff through comments and FB Messenger. All of these interactions help to create a sense of connectedness and community between you and your existing
            and future potential customers. In addition, having a FB Business page can also help in you in the search engines. Because FB is such a massive website, often your FB Business page will show up in Google search, giving you even more exposure
            online - which means more opportunities for new potential buyers to find you
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial; padding-bottom: 25px; text-align: justify;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%; text-align:center;">
        <div class="overall-score">
          <div class="score-wrapper" style="width:175px; height:175px; margin:0 auto;font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
            <img src="images/visibility-score-icon.png" style="width:175px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;" />
            <div style="position: relative; top:-140px; text-align: center;">
              <div class="score" style="font-size:
                                        60px;line-height: 50px;">2</div>
              <div class="slash" style="background: #0a2238;
                                        height: 2px;
                                        width: 100px;
                                        margin: 10px auto;"></div>
              <div class="total" style="font-size: 36px;
                                        line-height: 36px;">20</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 style="color: #0B79B9; text-align: center;">Visibility & Online Presence</h3>
        <ul style="text-align:center;padding: 0; margin:0 auto">
          <li style="display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Bad
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Poor
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Good
          </li>
          <li style=" display: inline-block;position: relative;padding: 2px 5px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: 1px;">
            Great
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70%; border-left: 10px solid #0B79B9; padding-left: 30px;">
        <h3 style="color: #0b79b9;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 24px;
                        margin-bottom: 5px;">Items You Need to Improve:</h3>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
          <div style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;">
            question_name<span style="color: #0b79b9;">No</span>
          </div>
          <div class="answer">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:10%;">name</td>
                <td>
                  <img src="images/icon-star-filled.png" style="width:25px;" />
                  <img src="images/icon-star-empty.png" style="width:25px;" />

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table style="width: 100%; background: #0A2238; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 30px; vertical-align: top;">
                  <img src="images/check-square.png" />
                </td>
                <td style="color: #fff; vertical-align: top; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                  name
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            Having a Facebook Business page has a lot of benefits. For starters, Facebook has 1.19 Billion users, who you can target right down to the town or city that you live in.
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This one is the screenshot of PDF

[image]

Comment: I made a snippet and pasted the screenshot. Your HTML does not validate

Comment: @mplungjan do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. But you have a better chance to fix it with a valid HTML page